# Make Pagination At SSRS Without Group

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

How can I set the pagination for my reports when showed in browser, without considering group??

Is there any solution for handle it with `ReportViewer` control properties?

Or what Is the solution for handle in business intelligence?

Comment: The ReportViewer (or PDF output) handles pagination automatically, unless you add extra page breaks in your report definition.  Is there something you are trying to do, or just asking how it works?

Comment: All records are displayed in one page as default, I want to have paging for my report.
And I can't find any solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the report properties there is a setting called `InteractiveSize`. This is what determines the automatic page breaks. In order for a report to show everything on one page, you would need to set the `Height` to 0. You can always add additional page breaks, but this is the default behavior which takes advantage of the page navigation controls at the top.